# Turn 0.5 to 1 instead of 0

Tags: c, double, rounding

My cyclomatic complexity in this C program is supposed to be 1, so I can't write if else statements.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{ 
    int U,V;
    scanf("%d %d",&U,&V);
    printf("%0d",(U*V)/2);
}
```

Comment: What are the entered values?

Comment: An unrelated question: What is the `0` in `%0d` there for?

Comment: There will never be a 0.5 in there. It is integer arithmetic, but you can do `(U * V + 1) / 2` to round supposed halves upwards.

Comment: Fwiw: Requiring a cyclomatic complexity of 1 in a program that uses `scanf` doesn't sound like a good idea. You would want to check that the `scanf` succeeds and then you're up to a cyclomatic complexity of 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression `(U*V)/2` performs integer division since all operands are integers.  This truncates any fractional part.

If you want to round up, you first need to perform floating point division, which you can do by changing one operand to a floating point type.  Then you can pass the result to the `round` function which rounds to the nearest integer, with the .5 case being rounded up.

```
printf("%0d",(int)round((U*V)/2.0));
```